# Why do you have to cast objects when calling particular methods of a subclass?

Tags: java, casting, instantiation

So, for example,

```
Person p = New Person()

Person z = New Adult()
```

Let's say the Adult Class had it's own method called drive(), why couldn't I do:

`z.drive()`

I know this won't work, but what is the logic behind this not working? When you say: `Person z = New Adult()`, aren't you specifying it is an `Adult` instance?

Comment: Because you could write `z = p;` in between `Person z = new Adult();` and `z.drive()`, and `p` has no `drive()` method. The compiler doesn't check what happens in between declaration and usage.

Comment: This is polymorphism. You reach only parent's methods in compile time. But in runtime child class's method is working. This is seperating interface and implementation by upcasting.

Comment: `Person z = New Adult()` it does what is written : variable `z` is a Person object and nothing else. See other answers concerning Java basic concepts and strong/weak typing.

Comment: "When you say: `Person z = New Adult()` ..." will never happen because it will not compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When you say: `Person z = New Adult()`, aren't you specifying it is an `Adult` instance?

You're creating an `Adult` object, but the declaration `Person z` says that the variable `z` is allowed to refer to *any* kind of person, not just an adult.  You could write `z = new Child()` on the very next line.

When you call a method on `z`, Java checks that it's valid for all objects that the variable *could* refer to.  It doesn't analyze the preceding code to try to figure out what specific type it actually *does* refer to, because in most cases that isn't possible.  (The variable could've been passed in as a method argument, for example, or it could've been set to either an `Adult` or `Child` based on an `if` statement.)  There may be specific cases where it's guaranteed that the variable will refer to a specific class, but the Java language doesn't treat those cases specially.  If the variable was declared with type `Person`, you can only call `Person` methods on it.

If you write `Adult z = new Adult()`, then you can call `z.drive()`, because the variable is guaranteed to refer only to adults, never children.

Answer (score 2):

The "logic" behind it not working is because that's how Java was designed to work. Java is a **statically typed** language which means that every variable has a declared type at compile time. Java is also **strongly typed** which means that the values that can be held and the operations that are supported are limited to the declared type. This enforcement is called [type safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety).

The advantage of a [static type checking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Static_type_checking) is that the compiler will prevent you from assigning incompatible types or calling methods that are not available. Errors can be caught at compile time vs runtime.

Try a search for "strong vs. weak typing" which will give many more details, arguments, and the pros/cons of the approaches.

Answer (score 0):

You asked this, I quote:

> When you say: Person z = New Adult(), aren't you specifying it is an
>   Adult instance?

No, just the opposite, more precisely:

```
//Main.java, first version.
class Person { 
    public void drive() {
        System.out.println("Person.drive");
    }
}

class Adult extends Person {

    @Override 
    public void drive() {
        System.out.println("Adult.drive");
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person p = new Person();
        p.drive();  // Person.drive

        Person a = new Adult();
        a.drive();  // Adult.drive
    }
}
```

Second Variation, this time Person has NO drive() method:

```
//Main.java, second version.
class Person {}

class Adult extends Person {

    // NO overriding here ..
    public void drive() {
        System.out.println("Adult.drive");
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person p = new Adult(); // 1

        // Now this cast is needed:
        Adult  a = (Adult) p;   // 2

        a.drive();  // Adult.drive(), as before  // 3
    }
}
```

Put these two separate programs in a Main.java, respectively, compile and run.

Let's consider the second version. Behold the lines marked with //1 and //2.
In //1 what's happening is the so-called slicing of class Adult. Adult is an extension of Person and therefore has the privilege to claim more memory than a Person object. But you assign a Person to an Adult object, so not all the memory of the bigger Adult object *might* be initialzed.

Therefore, Jave urges you to cast the Person to an *real* Adult object in //2, so that you show it that you *know* what you're doing. Only *then* are you permitted to call a.drive() in //3.

Hope, that helps to clarify things a bit.

Regards, Micha